# Lose password after sign in using Google provider

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an Android app with use Firebase authentication using email and password. Recently added Google provider now my users can sign in wih his Google account, the problem is the following

There's an existing user `example@gmail.com` registered on my app, later the user sign in with his Google account Firebase automatically change the provider of the account from email to Google, the problem the user sign out and try to login with his email/password and got a message

> The password is invalid or the user does not have a password

I understand why happens, but users (you know they are users) get frustrated because can't login with his email/password

There's some way to tell Firebase to keep the user password or when a user login with Google and this convertion happens in order to notify to user

*Note* My app only allow one account per email

Answer (score 0):

I found there's a method [fetchProvidersForEmail](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#fetchProvidersForEmail(java.lang.String)) I asume I can build a flow over that method that check which provider have the user and allow the user chose if want to keep if old password by asking and linking account or just continue